# What are the graphics editors that can be built upon?

Tags: graphics, scripting, editor, extensibility, vector-graphics

I want to start off with a capable vector graphics drawing/editing program and extend it to create a visual designer for a project I'm working on.

Do you know of a graphics editor that can be built upon? Maybe open source? Users should already be able to freely draw and color graphics, and any form of grouping / arranging elements is a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) or [Karbon14](http://www.koffice.org/karbon) for vector graphics.

For inkscape, you [have access to the API](http://inkscape.modevia.com/doxygen/html/namespaceinkscape_1_1api.php) and there is a [proposal for a Python extention](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ImprovingPythonExtensionAPI).

If you don't *need* colours, you could easely use the [Dia Python Plugin](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/).

Comment: As a follow up, I have written a very small extension for Inkscape which allows you to type a few lines of python script directly into inkscape and iterate it over a selection etc. http://www.smanohar.com/inkscape.php